# File is not on the newest commit

Tags: git, merge

we recenlty ran across a weird behaviour in our git at work and as noone really understood how it happened I am going to give it a try here ;)

We recently had an issue where a file was not updated to the newest commit and we couldn't figure out how that happend / how to prevent it in the future and to properly fix it. Any help is much appreciated

Now let's describe first the issue in more detail we saw and then I describe the workflow we use (as I kind of fear that it was simply that. An issue in our workflow)

We had a file. Let's call it `index.php`. We merged the branch `master` (where the state was correct) into the `develop` branch and the file didn't recieved any update.

Upon further inspection we found out following

`git log -p index.php`

```
commit 4689e60f87df4af989b7020a90b1cb186c6d5e04
Author: A Colleague
Date:   Fri Sep 25 14:50:24 2020 +0200

    Message // We did some stuff

diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
index cfde79447..b82010ac5 100644


commit 176a2c3142dfd4c20606f0838e99efbd55da91a4
Author: Another Colleague
Date:   Mon Apr 29 08:42:14 2019 +0200

    Message // Did some other stuff

diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
index 264b5a5b2..cfde79447
```

We realised that the changes I just commit were not there. Why not? We looked further into it and I ran a

`git log -p --follow index.php`
and look and behold. We got the missing commit

```
commit 854ba270959151982c2ccc14573a47ae5ea568cc
Author: Me Myself and I
Date:   Wed Nov 11 18:57:46 2020 +0100

    Changes // I did the stuff I needed

diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
index cfde79447..b3f7bd07e 100644


commit 4689e60f87df4af989b7020a90b1cb186c6d5e04
Author: A Colleague
Date:   Fri Sep 25 14:50:24 2020 +0200

    Message // We did some stuff

diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
index cfde79447..b82010ac5 100644


commit 176a2c3142dfd4c20606f0838e99efbd55da91a4
Author: Another Colleague
Date:   Mon Apr 29 08:42:14 2019 +0200

    Message // Did some other stuff

diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
index 264b5a5b2..cfde79447
```

So. What I saw aswell is (as seen in the last line of every commit log message. We see the change of a hash. I am not quite sure what exactly this hash is for. However as you can see the missing commit that I was looking for had a different starting has. It used the one from the commit before the actuall commit before its commit.

According to `man git log` the follow flag follows the commit history even upon changed file names. However I don't see any indication on a changed file name?

I imagine that this is the main issue. However I am not sure how that happened / how to prevent it and how to properly fix it if it should happen again

Explanation as to how we work with git

For simplicity reasons

We have two repositories. Repo A and Repo B

Every repo contains of at least 3 Brands

- master
- release
- develop

If we work on features we create a new branch from the master tree, merge it with no-ff into the develop. Once the customer says its ready to release the branch gets merged via no-ff into the branch release

Now it can happen that we need to copy stuff from Repo A to Repo B.

How we do this right now is.

- We go into Repo A.
- Add Repo B as remote repository
- create a new remote branch in Repo B
- cherry pick all the changes into that remote branch
- merge that remote branch via no-ff into the target remote branch

I am open for Ideas / solutions what has caused this and if you got any questions just go ahaed and ask :)
Thanks!

Edit: As asked by the comment the output for `git log --graph --oneline --all`

The commit I added later is now the second in line. And I have no clue why

```
...

* 4689e60f8 Message // We did some stuff
| diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
| index cfde79447..b82010ac5 100644

...    
| * 854ba2709 Changes // I did the stuff I needed
|/  
|   diff --git a/index.php b/index.php
|   index cfde79447..b3f7bd07e 100644
```

Comment: It would be helpful to say `git log --graph --oneline --all` and show the start of that, so that we see how the commit relate to each other.

Comment: Anyway, isn't this merely a presentational aspect of how `git log` behaves when you rename a file and log by file name? And nothing you have said has _anything_ to do with where HEAD is, so it's hard to see what that is doing in your title.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was the HEAD of the file. I removed it from the Title :)
And the renaming was my fault. It was late yesterday and I mixed up html and php when anonymizing the file name. The file never got renamed.

I also added the output as you asked. thanks

Comment: Ok, so I still don't see what the issue is. Your first log output traces the history of the file on this branch. 854ba2709 is on a different branch so it doesn't appear.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But why would it be on a different branch? Do you know that?
I explicitly merged the branch that had those commits into the branch that I show the git log from

Comment: But `git log -p index.php` does not follow merged branches. That is my whole point in my earlier comments. All that is happening here is the normal behavior of `git log` with a file name. Did you try reading the manual? It explains this. It’s called history simplification.